# How do I combine the first character of a cell with another cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with first names in Column A and surnames in Column B. I want to create a third Column C that contains the first character from the first name and adds it to the surname, creating *first initial + surname*.

```
First Name    Last Name    Combined Name
John          Smith        jsmith
```

How can I do this using Excel?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1), B1)
```

Assuming A1 holds 1st names; B1 Last names

Comment: this formula is static cause you wrote A1, can you tell if I can make it dynamic

Comment: Just drag the cell from bottom right corner or double click to expand to all rows...

Answer (score 20):

Personally I like the & function for this

Assuming that you are using cells A1 and A2 for John Smith

```
=left(a1,1) & b1
```

If you want to add text between, for example a period

```
=left(a1,1) & "." & b1
```

Comment: I agree...I hate having to type "CONCATENATE(..." rather than just the & symbol

Comment: Indeed. I could see the point of a concatenate function if you could pass a range in, but... you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Use following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(LOWER(MID(A1,1,1)),LOWER( B1))
```

for

```
Josh Smith = jsmith
```

note that A1 contains name and B1 contains surname

Answer (score 1):

This is what formula I used in order to get the first letter of the first name and first letter of the last name from 2 different cells into one:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(F10,1),LEFT(G10,1))
Lee Ackerman = LA
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no one is using semicolons. This is how it works for me:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;1); B1)
```

Solutions with comma produce an error in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

QUESTION was: suppose T john is to be converted john T, how to change in excel?

If text "T john" is in cell A1

```
=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)," ",LEFT(A1,1))
```

and with a nod to the & crowd

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&" "&LEFT(A1,1)
```

takes the right part of the string excluding the first 2 characters, adds a space, adds the first character.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.