# In Excel.. How do take the first letter of a name and add it to their last name in another column

Tags: excel

In column E I have a list of 400 first names and in column F I have a list of their last names. How do I merge the first letter with the last name in another column. Column G is what I want in the below example.

Example

```
ColE        ColF              ColG
John        Smith             JSmith
Mike        Tomas             MTomas
Jill        Lake              JLake
```

Comment: I'd probably find an `excel` library in `c#`, and make a `c#` application to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: How do I take the first character of 1 cell and prepend it to another cell and place it in a 3rd cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534062/excel-how-do-i-take-the-first-character-of-1-cell-and-prepend-it-to-another-cel)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LEFT()` function and the ampersand to concatenate

```
=LEFT(e1,1)&f1
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula in column G will get what you want:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(E1,1),F1)
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2,1),F2)
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(E3,1),F3)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

In Column G, try

```
 left(E1,1) & F1
```